# Python language server fails to start in VSCode 1.84.0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

With the latest official `Python` extension, Pylance fails to index python files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igbXu.png)
The output of the `Python language server` output tab is:

```
2023-12-13 15:30:15.510 [info] [Error - 3:30:15 PM] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:15.510 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at _.provideFoldingRanges (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:60863)
2023-12-13 15:30:15.657 [info] [Error - 3:30:15 PM] Request textDocument/semanticTokens/full failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:15.657 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at J.provideDocumentSemanticTokens (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:50270)
2023-12-13 15:30:15.734 [info] [Error - 3:30:15 PM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:15.734 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at Arguments.r (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2457823)
    at s.provideDocumentSymbols (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:39147)
2023-12-13 15:30:16.459 [info] [Error - 3:30:16 PM] Request textDocument/inlayHint failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:16.459 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at o (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2483240)
    at Y.provideInlayHints (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:57757)
2023-12-13 15:30:17.641 [info] [Error - 3:30:17 PM] Sending document notification textDocument/didSave failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:17.641 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendNotification (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2385241)
    at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2462035)
2023-12-13 15:30:17.985 [info] [Error - 3:30:17 PM] Notify file events failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:17.985 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendNotification (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2385241)
    at t.Delayer.<anonymous> (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2397376)
2023-12-13 15:30:18.097 [info] [Error - 3:30:18 PM] Sending document notification textDocument/didSave failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:18.097 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendNotification (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2385241)
    at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2462035)
2023-12-13 15:30:26.395 [info] [Error - 3:30:26 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:26.395 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:50.252 [info] [Error - 3:30:50 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:50.252 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:51.230 [info] [Error - 3:30:51 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:51.230 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:52.114 [info] [Error - 3:30:52 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:52.114 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:53.165 [info] [Error - 3:30:53 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:53.165 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:53.360 [info] [Error - 3:30:53 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:53.360 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:53.586 [info] [Error - 3:30:53 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:53.586 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:54.598 [info] [Error - 3:30:54 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:54.598 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:54.628 [info] [Error - 3:30:54 PM] Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:54.628 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at T.provideDocumentHighlights (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:42716)
2023-12-13 15:30:55.129 [info] [Error - 3:30:55 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:55.129 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at z.provideCodeActions (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:43865)
2023-12-13 15:30:55.815 [info] [Error - 3:30:55 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:55.815 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at z.provideCodeActions (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:43865)
2023-12-13 15:30:56.780 [info] [Error - 3:30:56 PM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:56.780 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at g.provideHover (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:41905)
2023-12-13 15:30:58.248 [info] [Error - 3:30:58 PM] Sending document notification textDocument/didChange failed
2023-12-13 15:30:58.248 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendNotification (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2385241)
    at s (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2541189)
    at _0x5f0d0b.didChange (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.11.10/dist/extension.bundle.js:1:176782)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
2023-12-13 15:30:58.401 [info] [Error - 3:30:58 PM] Request textDocument/semanticTokens/range failed.
2023-12-13 15:30:58.401 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendRequest (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2383782)
    at le.provideDocumentRangeSemanticTokens (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:127:51747)
2023-12-13 15:30:58.432 [info] [Error - 3:30:58 PM] Sending document notification textDocument/didChange failed
2023-12-13 15:30:58.432 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendNotification (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2385241)
    at s (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2541189)
    at _0x5f0d0b.didChange (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.11.10/dist/extension.bundle.js:1:176782)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
2023-12-13 15:30:58.494 [info] [Error - 3:30:58 PM] Sending document notification textDocument/didChange failed
2023-12-13 15:30:58.494 [info] Error: Starting server failed
    at _.$start (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2399752)
    at _.sendNotification (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2385241)
    at s (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.0/out/client/extension.js:2:2541189)
    at _0x5f0d0b.didChange (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.11.10/dist/extension.bundle.js:1:176782)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

My `User File Indexing Limit` is set to 4000. Restarting VSCode helps sometimes, but it is not a solution I'd like in the long run. Wondering if that's a performance issue? How to optimize Pylance to the fastest speed while maintaining convenience? Any help appreciated.

I tried tweaking `User File Indexing Limit` to be less that number, but the problem persists.

Comment: Use extension pre -release version or try to switch the language server.

Comment: Are there any recent updates?

Comment: The problem persists for relatively large workspaces

Comment: If this is reproducible reliably on your machine, you can report it on GitHub for official response.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose

Comment: The problem with files not being indexed persists, yet in another form: some files in a workspace are not indexed fully (imports of some packages are sometimes ignored by the indexer for no reason). The original error is gone, presumably after a recent update of VScode

Comment: Try to [uninstall it completely](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall), and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this so maybe i could help, I tried disabling the extension and enabling it back and it is working perfectly now.
think u should try these too.

Comment: Thank you, but it was working fine about several methods and then required repeating the same procedure. It shouldn't be like this